# outlook.com rules copying messages that should be moved

Tags: outlook.com

I have a web server that I set up to send all notifications that may be of use to debug/investigate server issues to my outlook.com account. I use this account as a backup in the case I lose access to the server completely, so I at least have some information that I can use to find out what the issue was and how to solve it.

I set up some rules to automatically sort messages into folders. The folder structure boils down to:

```
Server
├─LFD
│ ├─cxs
│ ├─Excessive Usage
│ ├─Modified Files
│ ├─Service Monitoring
│ └─...
├─Scanners
│ ├─ChkRoot
│ ├─RKHunter
│ └─Maldet
├─Cron Errors
└─...
```

This is a simplified view because it illustrates the problem well enough and I can't be bothered to type out the whole structure.

Some information that may be useful to know:

1. All emails are sent from `root@<servername>`
2. All emails are sent to either `root@<servername>` OR a generic log email address that's setup with forwarders. Mail to root also gets forwarded here.

The rules are executed in this order:

1. Move all messages from `root@<servername>` to `Server`
2. Move all messages of which the subject line contains `LFD on <servername>` to `Server/LFD` AND stop processing rules
3. Move all messages of which the subject line contains `CXS scan on <servername>` to `Server/LFD/cxs` AND stop processing rules
4. (repeat rule 3 for all other `LFD` subfolders
5. Move all messages of which the subject line contains `ChkRoot on <servername>` to `Scanners/ChkRoot`
6. (repeat rule 5 for all other scanners)
7. Move all messages of which the subject line contains `Anacron job on <servername>` to `Cron Errors`

This used to work perfectly, where all notifications were first moved to the `Server` folder and then sorted into their specific folders. I set it up this way so that all notifications, even those for which I didn't set up specific rules, would *at least* be moved to the `Server` folder.

Unfortunately, a few weeks ago, the rules started showing some strange behaviors. I didn't modify the rules at all before this happened.

Now, when I receive some notifications (so far I've noticed it for all scanners, as well as those that should be moved to `LFD`), they are first moved to the `Server` folder, and then *copied* to their specific folder. This leaves me with all those notifications appearing in two folders. This is especially annoying because I usually check the `Server` folder to see if there's any messages that need their own folder and rule.

I have created a screenshot of the generic and specific rules:

**Generic rule (applied to all messages)**
[image]

**Specific rule (applied after generic rule)**
[image]